# Safari Bug? » Double sound track when launching a YouTube video in Safari 5.1

Tags: osx-lion, safari, youtube, safari-5

I am desperate... Please help me with this problem

Every time I launch a YouTube video in Safari [5.1 (7534.48.3) / Lion OS X 10.7.1] the YouTube page is served and the video starts (sound included). 
With a short delay a second audio stream of the same video is served.
When I stop the video player, the second (i.e. the delayed) audio stream continues.
After closing the browser tab the audio stops.
I can demo this with this URL http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6oXZSQeGbk , but any YouTube URL will do.
N.B. No other video playback apps are running and there is no difference when using Flash or HTML playback.

What can cause this behaviour and HOW do I get rid of it?

Comment: Do you use third-party Safari extensions, plugins, Input Managers, SIMBL plugins, etc.? Can you reproduce this behavior on another user account?

Comment: I can't understand why I did not check the extensions before I asked for help here! :-(
I disabled all extensions and the phenomenon vanished. 
I discovered that the extension FlashToHTML5 by Joris Vervuurt (@ http://www.joris-vervuurt.com/page9/page9.php) caused the problem. 
Thank you Daniel for the hint. 
Problem solved!

Comment: I posted an answer. Please accept so the system can consider this problem solved.

Comment: Where/How can I accept the answer Daniel? .. I checked the checkmark in front of the answer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: This is a universal issue; I'm on Chrome and it's happening, and specific channels as well. Disable all addons (AdBlock did it for me) much like he said. The reason I'm answering is because it happens to all browsers with addons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable all third-party Safari extensions and plugins, Input managers etc. and check if the problem disappears.

If it does, you can selectively enable and disable them to find the culprit.

Comment: That did the trick Daniel :-) I found the extension that caused the behaviour. The extension is called FlashToHTML5 by Joris Vervuurt » [http://joris-vervuurt.com/page9/page9.php](http://joris-vervuurt.com/page9/page9.php). I uninstalled the extension. Problem solved!  THANKS!